# What does "time folds in on itself" metaphorically refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I wonder if it metaphorically refers to time coming to a halt. There are several examples of this phrase in books.

> "Time is folding in on itself. No, I correct myself. Time is always
> folded in on itself, the past like shadows we can’t shake off, and now
> I feel them surrounding me, wraiths drawing in to choke me."
>
> "When you are in darkness, time folds in on itself, surreal and
> elastic. It bellows like an accordion, stretching and then
> collapsing."
>
> "The minutes slip by strangely, like time is folding in on itself, too
> fast and too slow all at once."
>
> "Time folded in on itself until I couldn't tell if I was homesick for
> the moment I'd left behind, or already missing the time I was
> currently in but might have to leave."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for the precise "meaning" of highly figurative language that's desperately (not very successfully, imho) trying to eff the ineffable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm not looking for an exact meaning. I just can't figure out what it metaphorically refers to.

Comment: It's metaphorically referring to Time in the same way we normally refer to the other three *(**spatial**)* dimensions. In which context we often say that something like a sheet of paper is 2-dimensional (but obviously *everything* that's "real" has 3 spatial and 1 time dimension). But your guess is as good as mine when it comes to how folded paper and folded time can be equated.

Comment: @BeatsMe - you should read some better books.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I didn't say I read the books.

Answer (score 2):

I have occasionally met this metaphor (don't ask me where - I can't remember). In all cases
I have understood it as follows.

The metaphor views time not as a unidirectional and rigid 1-dimensional scale along which we move (the classical physics view, echoing the view of our 3-dimensional movement through space), but as a ribbon of events that flows over us. From that perspective, the ribbon may fold and bend, sometimes touching us with previous events, and it may move over us slowly or fast as we recall and re-experience past events. If the touch is strong, we may even find it difficult to distinguish the present from the past.

Comment: Very good explanation!

Comment: Good answer; Are you aware of Möbius strip? :)

Comment: Thanks indeed - yes, I used to make them long ago.

Comment: @Stockfish - Actually, Möbius got hauled away by the vice squad.